# C# WPF MVVM CollectionView Filter - Apply to Sub-ViewModels

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm building a WPF/MVVM application that displays some lists below each other.
My MainViewModel contains in addition to the lists a textbox, whose text content I want to use as a filter for my lists.
However, these lists are not in the MainViewModel, but in sub-controls (UserControl2_*).

If the filter property is in the same ViewModel as the ICollectionView, then filtering works (see CollectionViewFilter in **ViewModel2.cs**), but I don't understand how to apply a filter to multiple Sub-ViewModels.

Is there an MVVM compliant method to pass the filter through to the sub-controls?
Or do I need to pass the collections up so that I can access them from the ViewModel, where the filter property is also set?

If there is any more code you want me to upload or adapt, let me know and I will edit my question.

```
 ___________________      ___________________   
|Search:            |    |Search: FG         |  
|___________________|    |___________________|  
|Collection         |    |Collection         |  
| _________________ |    | _________________ |  
||UserControl1_1   ||    ||UserControl1_1   ||  
|| _______________ ||    || _______________ ||  
|||UserControl2_1 |||    |||UserControl2_1 |||  
|||* ABCDEF       |||    |||* BCDEFG       |||  
|||* BCDEFG       |||    |||* CDEFGH       |||  
|||* CDEFGH       |||    |||_______________|||  
|||_______________|||    ||_________________||  
|| _______________ ||    | _________________ |  
|||UserControl2_2 |||    ||UserControl1_2   ||  
|||* ABCDEF       |||    || _______________ ||  
|||* UVWXYZ       ||| => |||UserControl2_3 |||  
|||_______________|||    |||* BCDEFG       |||  
| _________________ |    |||_______________|||  
||UserControl1_2   ||    || _______________ ||  
|| _______________ ||    |||UserControl2_4 |||  
|||UserControl2_3 |||    |||* CDEFGH       |||  
|||* LMNOPQ       |||    |||_______________|||  
|||* BCDEFG       |||    ||_________________||  
|||* UVWXYZ       |||    |___________________|  
|||_______________|||                           
|| _______________ ||                           
|||UserControl2_4 |||                           
|||* ABCDEF       |||                           
|||* CDEFGH       |||                           
|||_______________|||                           
||_________________||                           
|___________________|
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new CollectionViewModel();
    }
}
```

**MainViewModel.xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding FilterText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModels1}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:UserControl1 />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

**CollectionViewModel.cs**

```
public class CollectionViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public ObservableCollection<ViewModel1> ViewModels1 { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

**ViewModel1.cs**

```
public class ViewModel1 : ObservableObject
{
    public ObservableCollection<ViewModel2> ViewModels2 { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

**ViewModel2.cs**

```
public class ViewModel2 : ObservableObject
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<ViewModel3> ViewModels3 { get; set; }
    public ICollectionView CollectionView3 { get; }

    private string _filter = string.Empty;
    public string Filter
    {
        get => _filter;
        set => SetProperty(ref _filter, value);
    }

    public ViewModel2(Model2 model2)
    {
        model = model2;
    
        ViewModels3 = new ObservableCollection<ViewModel3>();

        CollectionView3 = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ViewModels3);
        CollectionView3.Filter = CollectionViewFilter;
    }
    
    private bool CollectionViewFilter(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is ViewModel3 viewModel)
        {
            return viewModel.Name.Contains(Filter, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        }
        return true;
    }
    // ...
}
```

**ViewModel3.cs**

```
public class ViewModel3 : ObservableObject
{   
    private Model3 _model;
    public ViewModel3(Model3 model3)
    {
        _model = model3;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get => _model.Name;
        set => SetProperty(_model.Name, value, _model, (model, name) => model.Name = name);
    }
}
```

**+++**

**Solution based on [mm8's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70584254/4496150):**

I have extended my CollectionViewModel.cs as follows:

```
private string filterText = string.Empty;
public string FilterText
{
    get => filterText;
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref filterText, value);
        foreach(var vm1 in ViewModels1)
        {
            foreach(var vm2 in vm1.ViewModels2)
            {
                vm2.Filter = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In ViewModel2 the refresh for the CollectionView was missing:

```
public string Filter
{
    get => _filter;
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref _filter, value);
        CollectionView3.Refresh();
    }
}
```

**+++**

**Solution based on [mm8's second advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70584254/4496150) (using a messenger):**

Since I am working with Microsoft.Toolkit.MVVM, I used [IMessenger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/mvvm/messenger) interface. For this I added the class **FilterTextChangedMessage.cs**:

```
public class FilterTextChangedMessage : ValueChangedMessage<string>
{
    public FilterTextChangedMessage(string value) : base(value)
    {
    }
}
```

I changed the FilterText property of the **CollectionViewModel.cs** as follows:

```
public string FilterText
{
    get => filterText;
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref filterText, value);
        WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new FilterTextChangedMessage(value));
    }
}
```

I changed the **ViewModel2.cs** as follows:

```
public class ViewModel2 : ObservableRecipient, IRecipient<FilterTextChangedMessage> {
    public ViewModel2(Model2 model)
    {
        WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<FilterTextChangedMessage>(this, (r, m) => {
            Filter = m.Value as string;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the `CollectionViewModel` where the `FilterText` property is defined already have references to the child view models via the `ViewModels1` property? Then you should set the filter using the strong references in this collection.

Comment: You mean I iterate down to my UserControl2 related ViewModels in the CollectionView's filter property and set their own filter property? I did it this way and it works. Is this a clean (MVVM) approach? Sounds almost too simple.

Comment: Yes, apart from the fact that it creates a strong relationship between your view model classes but that's another story. See my answer for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `CollectionViewModel`, where the `FilterText` property is defined, already has a strong reference to the child view models via the `ViewModels1` property, you could set the filter of these by iterating through this source collection.

This is perfectly fine as far as MVVM is concerned. The application logics stays in the view model where it belongs.

Keeping a strong reference form one view model type to another does however introduce a coupling that tend to make the application harder to maintain. But that's another issue that already comes with the `ViewModels1` property.

This kind of issue is typically solved by using a messenger or [event aggregator](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/02/28/using-the-event-aggregator-pattern-to-communicate-between-view-models/) for communicating between different view models. In this case, you would then send some kind of filter event from the `CollectionViewModel` and handle this event in the child view models.

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked. I have attached the implementation of your suggestion as a solution to the end of my question.
And thanks for the tip about messenger and event aggregator, I will have a look at that too.

Comment: I have added a implementation of your second suggestion (messenger), too.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to link the `CollectionView`s and the filter method at some point, so your UserControl needs to allow that. I can think of three ways to do it:

1. Have your UserControl handle its own `CollectionView`, and add a method to configure your filter (take a `Predicate<object>` as parameter and set that to the Filter property).
2. Have your UserControl expose a method which returns a `CollectionView` for your list, and do everything in the MainWindow. Less pretty, but still probably alright, and avoids creating unnecessary stuff when you just want to display a list without any option.
3. The most "MVVM" way to do it would be to add a `DependencyProperty` to your UserControl, with a `PropertyChangedCallback` that updates the filtering of objects. Then you can bind to a property of your mainwindow's viewmodel, and update that property based on your text field. Here's an example from some code i have :

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty BlurRadiusProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("BlurRadius", typeof(double), typeof(FastShadow),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
        0.0,
        FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender,
        new PropertyChangedCallback((o, e) =>
        {
            var f = (FastShadow)o;
            if ((double)e.NewValue < 0)
                f.BlurRadius = 0;
            f.CalculateGradientStops();
        })));

public double BlurRadius
{
    get => (double)this.GetValue(BlurRadiusProperty);
    set => this.SetValue(BlurRadiusProperty, value);
}
```

Comment: Phew, I'm really having a hard time understanding your third way. WPF/MVVM/Binding are still new territory for me. The DependencyProperty can only be passed up one control at a time, right? Do I need a chain of DependencyProperties then?

Comment: A DependencyProperty will be available when you add your UserControl in xaml. So if you have, say, a DependencyProperty named Filter, you can set it a value from xaml. The value you set will be a Binding to a property of your MainWindow's viewmodel. Then, when you update that property, your UserControl will receive the new value of the filter. You can use the PropertyChangedCallback to update the CollectionView based on that filter value when it changes.

Comment: I have created a DependencyProperty _MyFIlterDP_ and have used it with `MyFilterDP="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.FilterText}"` to the FilterText property of the CollectionViewModel. The changes arrive in the control, but how do I access it in ViewModel2 to apply the filter?

Comment: You could add that DP to UserControl1 (OneWay should be enough), and in the callback iterate over all ViewModel2's CollectionViews to update their filter. Your filter method then goes up to UserControl1.